# How do I upgrade to Kubuntu+1?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I know that Ubuntu can be upgraded to a development release by starting `update-manager -d`

However, in Kubuntu `update-manager` is not installed so I suppose some KDe-specific program need to be used.

Comment: Note to myself: for the last couple of releases I need to run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp` before running the upgrade

Comment: Oops, the right command is `sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo do-release-upgrade -f kde -d`

Comment: Awesome, `-f kde` even provides some GUI.